# I manage to save, but not to LOAD (Serialization)

Tags: java, serialization

I´m making a small game and are now working with serialization. I have managed to save the current state of my `battleground` object, but I can not seem to load it.

This is my method that´s giving me syntax errors:

```
//Reads a Battleground object from disk.
private Object readFromFile() {
    FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("savegame.obj");
    ObjectInputStream restore = ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
    Object obj = restore.readObject();
    String name = (String) restore.readObject();
    restore.close();
}
```

I get the error message "cannot find symbol - method ObjectInputStream(java.io.FileInputStream). Looking the method up in Oracle Docs the parameter in the method is supposed to be of that type. I have imported the whole java.io library. Any inputs? Is this the wrong way to do it? I need a method to load the game. My other save-method looks like this:

```
// Saves the Battleground object to disk.
private void saveToFile() {
    try{
        // Serialize data object to a file
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Savegame.obj"));
        out.writeObject(battleground);
        out.close();

        // Serialize data object to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
        out.writeObject(battleground);
        out.close();

        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `new` keyword

```
new ObjectInputStream(saveFile)
```

I'm also wondering why are you calling `readObject()` twice

```
Object obj = restore.readObject();
String name = (String) restore.readObject();
```

when your `saveToFile()` code is writing only once

```
out.writeObject(battleground);
out.close();
```

Comment: Did you also check the double reads you're doing? I don't think it would work unless it's some other object.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Not my area this whole thing, so I´m learning as I go. Now I´m struggling with "Unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown."

So I´m still struggling, don´t know how to solve it. On the readFromFile()-method.

Comment: Add a `try catch` block within `readFomFile()` just like you've done in `saveToFile()` but change your catch to `} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` By catching `Exception` (super class) you automatically catch all the derived (base class) exceptions (like ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException) in one single catch block. `printStackTrace()` makes sure they don't go unreported and you see the exception on your console output.